# How to put camera sensor inside my Activity?

Tags: java, android, android-camera

There is an application made by another developer and I need to continue it. It has an `activity` with a button that calls the default camera app as an `intent` with `startActivityForResult`. It works ok when they take only one picture per app session. But now the client wants to be able to take various photos from different position of the place and then upload them all to the web server. So I need another way to do that, faster than opening the camera app for every picture.

For this I wish to load the camera directly in my activity, place a 'shoot' button, a label with the number of pictures taken, an imageView with the last image saved, and a button to finish. As an example I show you this printed screen from Internet.

The idea is to save a picture on every button click, and save the file names in an array.

How can I use the camera this way and control it with a custom button?

[image]

Comment: this https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#custom-camera and this https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-camera

Answer (score 0):

I also try to control the camera and I am using this [link](http://developer.android.com/training/camera/cameradirect.html)

I hope it is useful for you. It has helped me to fix several bugs